# Why Jackson’s ObjectMapper methods take raw TypeReference

Tags: java, generics, jackson, jackson2

Jackson 2 `ObjectMapper` class defines numerous generic methods for deserializing JSON strings, byte arrays, files, etc. to given Java types.

Target type is given in an argument to those methods.

Eg. a type may be given as a `Class<T>`, like in the method

```
public <T> T readValue(String content, Class<T> valueType)
```

which returns the same `T` object (and thus is type-safe to use).

But it may also be given as a `TypeReference<T>` (which can encode a complex generic type), so one can build eg. `new TypeReference<List<Long>> { }` to tell `ObjectMapper` that the input needs to be deserialized into a list of longs – it can be passed eg. into the method:

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
public <T> T readValue(String content, TypeReference valueTypeRef)
```

But that method takes **raw** `TypeReference` and not a generic `TypeReference<T>`, and thus one needs to manually add a generic parameter to the call:

```
objectMapper.<List<Long>>readValue(input, listOfLongs)
```

and if one makes a mistake in the provided type, the compiler cannot catch that. That would not be a problem if the method signature was

```
public <T> T readValue(String content, TypeReference<T> valueTypeRef)
```

which would tell the compiler that the returned value is always of the same type as the generic parameter of provided `TypeReference`, similarly to how it works with `Class<T>`.

**My question is – what is the reason behind such an API?** Why do Jackson methods take raw `TypeReference`? Are there any valid cases when returned object is really of a different type that that referenced by generic parameter of `TypeReference`?

PS: What also puzzles me is that a corresponding `convertValue` method takes not a raw type, but a wildcard one:

```
public <T> T convertValue(Object fromValue, TypeReference<?> toValueTypeRef)
```

and similarly `readValues`:

```
public <T> MappingIterator<T> readValues(JsonParser p, TypeReference<?> valueTypeRef)
```

and the `readValue(JsonParser, TypeReference)` actually [takes a fully qualified generic parameter](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/blob/325d6186f09ef52f9673d068b8e7fa18f91b8096/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.java#L2175):

```
public <T> T readValue(JsonParser p, TypeReference<T> valueTypeRef)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is already [reported as an issue](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1424), but was labeled as `3.x`.

There's a comment by the author of the library that explains why this hasn't been corrected yet:

> Looks like `ObjectMapper` API (and perhaps `ObjectReader` too) omits type-variable matching with `TypeReference`. This would make sense to change, but is likely to cause some source-compatibility issues (not binary), so perhaps do this in 3.0 and not earlier.

Comment: Seems it got fixed in 2.10 (although, as of time of this comment, the issue is till open).

Answer (score -2):

`TypeReference` abstract class is not meant to be used directly as a container for generic information. This is from the [javadoc](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/type/TypeReference.html):

> This generic abstract class is used for obtaining full generics type
>   information by sub-classing; it must be converted to ResolvedType
>   implementation (implemented by JavaType from "databind" bundle) to be
>   used.

Even if `ObjectMapper` accepted a parameterized `TypeReference` ,it wouldn't do the job since all generic specification like this `new TypeReference<List<Long>> { }` is completely erased at run time.

To pass generic information to Jackson's `ObjectMapper`, you need to create a `JavaType` instance:

```
JavaType type = mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, Long.class);
```

and then

```
List<Long> list = mapper.readValue(..., type);
```

Comment: `T` in `Class<T>` is also erased at run-time (but true, that it is a JVM `final` class which you cannot subclass to create an implementation that gives you different type information at runtime than is encoded in its generic parameter). Regardless, that does not answer my question why `readValue(String, TR)` takes raw `TypeReference`, `convertValue` takes `TypeReference<?>` and `readValue(JsonParser, TR)` actually takes `TypeReference<T>`…

Comment: Regardless, this sentence in the question "one can build eg. new TypeReference<List<Long>> { } to tell ObjectMapper that the input needs to be deserialized into a list of longs" is FALSE

Comment: passing the `Class` instances to `constructCollectionType()` allows Jackson to actually instantiate object out of these Classes as well as query their type with e.g. `isAssignableFrom()`

Comment: How is it wrong? `List<Long> value = new ObjectMapper().<List<Long>>readValue("[1, 2, 3]", new TypeReference<List<Long>>() { });` works for me.

It does not tell Jackson how to cunstruct this type (and I don’t know Jackson enough to tell how it actually decides how to instantiate it), but it seems to tell it fine what types need to be constructed.

Comment: Other more complex types also work, eg. `readValue(str, new TypeReference<List<EventDTO>>() { })` where `EventDTO` is a data class with properties annotated as `@JsonProperty`.

Comment: then I guess Jackson gets the type information from the annotations or some other configuration because **it does not** get it from the TypeReference.  You can try this `readValue(str, new TypeReference<Object>() { })` on the `EventDTO` json and see

Comment: Look at [this gist](https://gist.github.com/silmeth/ed06498d44770471bbd355f2df8f4d57) – it passes and has no other place indicating what class is expected inside `List` except the instance of anonymous `TypeReference` creation.

Comment: `TypeReference` uses [`Class.getGenericSuperclass()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getGenericSuperclass--) method in its abstract constructor to gain knowledge about its generics at runtime.

Comment: Please learn about type tokens. Here's a [blog post](http://gafter.blogspot.com.uy/2006/12/super-type-tokens.html) that explains them in detail. @silmeth is right here: `TypeReference` is a type token that holds information about some generic type. I don't know why they're using the raw version, though. Seems like a bug to me, it doesn't make any sense to have a non-generic type token...